# "RenderBox was not laid out" text field error in flutter

Tags: flutter-layout

I'm trying to put a textfield, the error does not appear, but I think I'm getting a logical error.
I guess sizing is required. But I couldn't understand where to specify.
And the screen is blank.
I don't know if I could explain it properly because my English is not good.

[image]

[image]

```
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Enter your email',
                  ),
                  validator: (String? value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter some text';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: null,
                    child: Text('Submit'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                    textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                  ),
                  onPressed: null,
                  child: const Text('Button'),
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextButton(
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                      ),
                      onPressed: null,
                      child: const Text('Button2'),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow you have to tell Flutter how should it size the two columns in the row. One of the possible solutions is to wrap the first column in an `Expanded` widget. As a result the second column will be drawn, its size is determined by the text sizes of `Button` and `Button2`). And then the first column will occupy all the remaining  space, that's what `Expanded` means. Code:

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded( // <--- this is added, the rest is unchanged
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Enter your email',
            ),
            validator: (String? value) {
              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter some text';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: null,
              child: Text('Submit'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextButton(
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          ),
          onPressed: null,
          child: const Text('Button'),
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
              ),
              onPressed: null,
              child: const Text('Button2'),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    )
  ],
),
```